# facebook api post on timeline via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook

hi and happy new year guys,

I would like to ask if its possible to post/publish a message via timeline using ajax or jquery-ajax?

currently my script is functionality/process like this one.... **first** user login which it will automatically add a cookie or site session mark as login. Also note I didn't store the facebook access token via db or cookie.

my question are
1. if I store the session of facebook how much time is the expiration time of the session token?
2. is there a way even I didn't add a facebook session when posting via AJAX?
3. is there a possibility I can post using ajax? if yes can you give me some link or tutorial on how to make this part.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

1) thats up to you, you're storing it.

2) Not sure what that means.

3) Really, you shouldn't use ajax calls across domains, but you can if you hack around it.

[Here's an example](http://www.webdevdoor.com/jquery/cross-domain-browser-json-ajax/)

Comment: do you know how much seconds/minutes/hour before the access token of facebook expired?